# Why parent table is not updated with new record when inserting record into child table (using table per class strategy)

Tags: hibernate, inheritance

I am having a parent entity(User) and two child entities(Registered User and Unregistered User) and using TABLE PER CLASS strategy implement this in database tables.

Therefore I have three tables in database. So when a user registers, I am creating Registered User entity and persist it. It creates a record in Registered User table but it doesn't insert any records into User table (parent table).

Can anyone please help to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Nirathan

Answer (score 0):

You might want to re-read the Javadoc on `InheritanceType`.

1. `JOINED`
   A strategy in which fields that are specific to a subclass are mapped to a separate table than the fields that are common to the parent class, and a join is performed to instantiate the subclass.
2. `SINGLE_TABLE`
   A single table per class hierarchy
3. `TABLE_PER_CLASS`
   A table per concrete entity class

What you describe as your expectations aligns more closely with `JOINED`.  In that case, attributes for the super class would be stored in its own table while attributes of the child class are stored separately in its own table.  In order to access a complete row, the JPA provider must execute a *JOIN* across all tables that participate to get a full row.

In the `TABLE_PER_CLASS` scenario, there will be a table for each concrete entity type, in your case one for `User`, `RegisteredUser`, and `UnregisteredUser` because all 3 are `@Entity` mappings.  The JPA provider treats them as separate entities but allows you to use polymorphism for your entity mappings where needed.

At the database level, if you look at the tables you'll notice the columns inherited from `User` are also present in the other two types.  When you create a subclass type, `RegisteredUser`, its `userName` property will be stored in the `RegisteredUser` table, not the `User` table.

Only if you create a `User` directly will the data be stored in `User`.

Comment: Thanks Naros. Is there any way to insert into User table when trying to insert a record to Registered User table in Table per class strategy?

Comment: The only way using that strategy would be to create both a `Registered` and plain `User` and insert 2 entities with the same data.  I'm not sure how useful that would be, but I don't know your domain model or reasons :)